# ASP.net MVC открытие бинарного файла(.dat) отображение его на странице

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Собственно есть файл с разрешением .dat 
Я задал свойства которые в нем указаны:

```
     public int version { get; set; }
     public sbyte[] name { get; set; }
     public ulong timestamp { get; set; }
```

После открыл файл через BinaryReader.

```
     string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/base.dat");
     MemoryStream MemoryCopy = new MemoryStream();
     FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path);
     fs.CopyTo(MemoryCopy);
     MemoryCopy.Seek(0, 0);
     BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(MemoryCopy);
     int version = r.ReadInt32();
     sbyte[] name = new sbyte[32];
     for (int i = 0; i <= 31; i++)
     {
         name[i] = r.ReadSByte();
     }
     ulong timestamp = r.ReadUInt64();
```

добавил в контролер отображение данного файла на html страницу, но там либо "0" нули или вообще пустая строка. 
В С# и в целом ASP.NET новичок, поэтому хотелось бы узнать от экспертов как правильно отображать информацию на странице из такого ввида формата файла.

Comment: "Я задал свойства которые в нем указаны" - ???

Comment: Нет единого стандарта на файлы типа .dat -- нужно знать структуру данных внутри. Для начала -- попробуйте добавить информацию о том, где вы берёте этот файл. Вы же его не с потолка взяли, а какое-то приложение его создаёт?

Comment: Браузеры кстати тоже не знают, как отображать подобный тип файла.

Comment: мне выдали такой файл, где указаны какие параметры есть =/.